помогите сделать так чтобы парсер работал и находил нужную информацию
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd



driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Укажите путь к драйверу, если он не в PATH
driver.get("https://xn---72-9cd9bqh6aic.xn--p1ai/katalog/noutbuki-i-netbuki/")

# Устанавливаем ожидание
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)  # Увеличиваем время ожидания до 15 секунд

# Массивы для хранения данных
models = []
descriptions = []
prices = []
dates = []


# def mr_proper ():
try:
        print("Ожидание загрузки страницы...")
        # Ждем, пока появится хотя бы один элемент с ноутбуками
        notebook_item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product')))
        print("Элементы найдены на странице!")

        # Извлекаем данные первого ноутбука
        model = notebook_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product__title').text
        price_text = notebook_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product__price').text

        try:
            description = notebook_item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product__description').text
        except:
            description = 'Нет описания'
        
        date_added = 'Неизвестно'  # Дата добавления отсутствует на сайте
    
        # Заполняем массивы
        models.append(model)
        descriptions.append(description)
        prices.append(price_text)
        dates.append(date_added)
        print("Данные успешно извлечены!")
    
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка при получении данных: {e}")
    
finally:
        # Закрываем драйвер
        driver.quit()
    
    # Сохранение данных в Excel
if models:
        data = pd.DataFrame({
            'type': ['Ноутбук'],
            'name': models,
            'description': descriptions,
            'price': prices,
            'date_added': dates
        })
    
        # Сохраняем DataFrame в Excel файл
        data.to_excel('first_notebook_info.xlsx', index=False)
        print("Данные сохранены в файл 'first_notebook_info.xlsx'")
else:
        print("Данные не найдены.")
       


# while True:
    


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Добавте в вопрос: что за информацию парсер должен парсить, и что не так с вашим кодом.
